# Merge 2 arrays into an array of maps

Tags: php, arrays

How do I merge two arrays like

```
$letters = ["A","B","C"];
$words = ["Alpha","Bravo","Charlie"];
```

Into an array of maps like

```
$result = [
    ["letter" => "A", "word" => "Alpha"],
    ["letter" => "B", "word" => "Bravo"],
    ["letter" => "C", "word" => "Charlie"]];
```

as efficiently and neatly as possible, I've tried looking at built-in functions and can't seem to find any that help.

Comment: You can make a simple loop

Comment: Is it significant that one array contains the initial letter of the word at corresponding index in second array or is that simply coincidence here?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to loop thru the arrays like:

```
$letters = ["A","B","C"];
$words = ["Alpha","Bravo","Charlie"];

$result = array_map(function( $letter, $word ){
    return [ 'letter' => $letter, 'word' => $word ];
}, $letters, $words);
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [letter] => A
            [word] => Alpha
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [letter] => B
            [word] => Bravo
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [letter] => C
            [word] => Charlie
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want one-liner,

```
$temp=array_map(function($l,$w){return array_combine(['letter','word'],[$l,$w]);},$letters,$words);
```

[array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) — Applies the callback to the elements of the given arrays
[array_combine](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) — Creates an array by using one array for keys and another for its values

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/j6tWm)

**Output:-**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [letter] => A
            [word] => Alpha
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [letter] => B
            [word] => Bravo
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [letter] => C
            [word] => Charlie
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's the `array_map()` method but I like this one as it's more down to earth and may be more explicit (at least it is for me) :

```
$letterCount = count($letters);
if (count($words) !== $letterCount) {
  // Throw an exception as this wont work in this case
}
$letterToWord = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < $letterCount; $i++) {
  $letterToWord[] = [
    'letter' => $letters[$i],
    'word' => $words[$i]
  ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Foreach will do:

```
foreach($letters as $k => $letter)
    $output[] = ['letter' => $letter, 'word' => $words[$k]];

var_export($output);
```

Output:

```
array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'letter' => 'A',
      'word' => 'Alpha',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'letter' => 'B',
      'word' => 'Bravo',
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      'letter' => 'C',
      'word' => 'Charlie',
    ),
  )
```